# Why is $f_1(n)$ not computable but $f_2(n)$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, computer-science, computability, turing-machines

I have the following two functions, where the first one is not computable and the second one is.

$$f_1(n)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & ,\text{if in the decimal representation of n appears in the decimal fraction expansion of} \ \pi \\
      0 & ,\text{else} 
   \end{cases}
$$

For example, if we have $\pi = 3.1415926 ...$. Then $f_1(14195) = 1$ but we don't know if $f_1(333)$ has a solution.

$$f_2(n)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & ,\text{if in the decimal representation of pi, there are n many consecutive 7's } \ \\
      0 & ,\text{else} 
   \end{cases}
$$

I am having a nightmare trying to understand why one is computable and the other one is not. If we take that $n =3$, then for $f_2$, we are trying to determine if $777$ appears in the decimal representation of $\pi$. But in $f_1$ we already saw that determining if $f(333)$ has a solution is not computable.

How are these two any different?

PS - the $n$ used in $f_1(n)$ is not the same as the one used in $f_2(n)$.

Comment: What is the claimed algorithm to solve $f_2$?

Comment: @Manlio There is no algorithm to be shown. The professor simply said that we have to prove that an algorithm exists but we don't have to show what that exact algorithm is.

Comment: Who says $f_1$ is not computable? It is currently not known if $f_1$ is computable or not, since it may turn out that $\pi$ is normal (currently an open problem). If $\pi$ is normal then $f_1(x) = 1$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: I think that this is implicitly assumed as this problem is more like an exercise for understanding computability.

Comment: @John_Krampf is absolutely right - it is consistent with current knowledge, and indeed *expected*, that $f_1$ is computable. However, this can be salvaged: for **any** real number $r$ we can define analogues $f_1^r$ and $f_2^r$ by replacing $\pi$ with $r$. Then **every** choice of $r$ results in $f_2^r$ being computable, but there are **some** $r$s which result in $f_1^r$ being non-computable. (So $\pi$ specifically is a red herring here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with $f_2(n)$. We have two cases:

**Case 1:** There are arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive $7$'s in $\pi$, then $f(n)=1, \forall n$, and this is clearly computable.

**Case 2:** There is a longest sequence of length $k$ of consecutive $7$'s somewhere in $\pi$ and $k$ is fixed. Hence, $$ 
     f_2(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1, & \text{if } n \leq k \\
         0, & k < n\end{array}\right. 
  $$
This is also clearly computable.

The function can be generalized (e.g. the apperance of the sequence $333$ is also computable).

$f_1(n)$ on the other hand claims to compute whether or not an arbitrary long sequence of numbers appears in $\pi$ (e.g. $1415926\cdots$). This is a dramatic difference! Now, recapitulate the following definition:

**Def.:** A (total) function $f: \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ is computable if there is a Turing machine $M$ that halts on every input $\omega$ with $f(\omega)$ as its output on the tape.

For $f_2(n)$, this is clear from the provided cases. Now, for $f_1(n)$ we assume that we have a sequence $\omega$ which is not in $\pi$ (and I do not want to discuss whether or not $\pi$ contains every possible number or not), then there is no way to build a Turing machine which halts on $\omega$ (because in order for our Turing machine to halt, we need to go through all of $\pi$), and therefore $f_1$ is not computable.

**Important note for $f_2$:** We only proved that $f_2$ is computable. Which function does the actual job is unknown (but also not important for this problem).

Comment: Ah. So the difference then lies in whether there exists such a fixed upper bound or not. If yes, then it's computable otherwise not?

Comment: The problem is decidable because we have shown (with the provided cases) that there **exists** a specific Turing machine deciding whether or not the given sequence is in $\pi$. **Which one of these Turing machines actually decides it correctly is unknown!**. Think of it as a list of Turing machines. One for each $k$. Which one is the correct one, we do not know. Their pure existence is sufficient for proving computability. Can we show this existence for $f_1$? If we can prove that $\pi$ contains every possible sequence then the answer is trivial. However, this is unsolved.