# How is $f_1(n)$ not computable but $f_2(n)$ is?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, pi, decidability

I came across these two introductory examples on the topic of computable.
$$f_1(n) = \begin{array}{cc}
  \Bigg \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & ,\text{if n appears in the decimal representation of} \ \pi \\
      0 & ,\text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\end{array}$$

$$f_2(n) = \begin{array}{cc}
  \Bigg \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & ,\text{if there are n-many 1's that appear in the decimal representation of} \ \pi \\
      0 & ,\text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\end{array}$$

According to my lecture, $f_1(n)$ is not computable but $f_2(n)$ is computable. $f_1(n)$ is not computable because no matter how many decimal places of $\pi$ we figure out, we can never be sure if $n$ will appear in there. That's because $\pi$ is irrational and just because it doesn't appear in the first $10^{15}$ decimal places, there is no guarantee that $n$ won't appear after it.

However, by the same argument, shouldn't $f_2(n)$ also be not computable? If in the first $10^{15}$ decimal places we can't find $n$-many $1$'s, there is no guarantee that we can't find it later. But this is wrong. $f_2(n)$ is indeed computable.

How can that be?

Comment: Did you look at the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037944/why-is-f-1n-not-computable-but-f-2n-is?rq=1)?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding "is computable" here.  For $f_2(n)$, the assertion is that there is a computable function which is $f_2(n)$: it either gives $1$ for all $n$, or it gives $1$ for all $n\le k$ and $0$ for all $n>k$ for some $k$, in either case easily computable. We do not know which, and if there is such a $k$ we do not know what $k$ is, but that does not stop $f_2(n)$ being called "computable".

Comment: These are confusing examples. Conjecturally $f_1(n) = 1$ for all $n$ which is certainly computable.